# Application to record each individual action in contact list

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, ios, iphone

I would like to record each good thing someone in my contactlist or maybe not in my contact list did to me or record a happy time we did togethers.
So i can read all the happy memories. See the list when i get angry at someone who might ever did a lot of good thIngs to me or send this list to them at the approprite time. I saw that there is a note section in my contact list. But i wonder Is there any apps that are more suit than this like organize by date and Save Photo.

Comment: Are you looking for OS X (desktop) software, or iOS (iPhone/iPad) software?

Comment: iphone 4s, ios5

Answer (score 1):

[*Bento*](http://www.filemaker.com/products/bento/) from Filemaker is an easy-to-use database application that leverages and integrates with Core Data—the storage bins for *Address Book* and *Calendar*. You could roll your own solution or use/modify an existing [*Personal Journal* template](http://solutions.filemaker.com/database-templates/detail.jsp?serial=2550449).